# Strange mismatch of Python arguments

Tags: python, parameter-passing

While testing some code, I was given an error:

> *TypeError: breadth_first_search() takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given*

The parameter bit of the function declaration looks like this:

```
def breadth_first_search(self, id: int, level=None)
```

The call looks like this:

```
tree.breadth_first_search(parent_id)
```

As far as I'm aware, this should be correct. I don't know why it would interpret my one argument (or two, including *self*) as four. Is there something plain that I'm missing?

--

For completeness, here's the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 4, in <module>
    tree = FeatureQuery.load_feature_tree("general", inventory)
  File "D:\Speechcraft\Python\core\ling_query.py", line 201, in load_feature_tree
    FeatureQuery.load_feature_node_recursive(feature_inventory, tree, results, l)
  File "D:\Speechcraft\Python\core\ling_query.py", line 221, in load_feature_node_recursive
    parent = tree.breadth_first_search(parent_id)
  File "D:\Speechcraft\Python\core\phonological_units.py", line 37, in breadth_first_search
    return self.breadth_first_search(self, id, next_level)
TypeError: breadth_first_search() takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

Comment: `tree.breadth_first_search(parent_id)` isn't the call you should be looking at. You should be looking at `return self.breadth_first_search(self, id, next_level)` at line 37 of file `D:\Speechcraft\Python\core\phonological_units.py`, which has an extra `self`.

Comment: Ah, that was it, how silly of me. This was my first attempt at Python recursion, so I was bound to trip over something. I'll post the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be a silly mistake. I accidentally included *self* as a parameter in the recursive call. Thanks go to [user2357112 supports monica](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2357112/user2357112-supports-monica).